# Specify AES key when using gpg

Tags: aes, gnupg

When using gpg to encrypt/decrypt a file with AES-256, is it possible to specify the 256-bit key directly (rather than have it derived from a passphrase)?

Comment: Gpg seems to only use passphrase derived keys. Openssl allows to give a raw hex key and IV : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc